# How to render a blob on a canvas element?

Tags: html, canvas, blob

How to render an image blob to a canvas element?

So far i have these two (simplified) functions to capture an image, transform it to a blob and eventually render the blob on a canvas 
[in this codepen, it just returns the default black image.](http://codepen.io/ohavben/pen/WxRQXL?editors=1010)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var photo;


function picToBlob() {
  var file = input.files[0];

  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    var newImg = document.createElement("img"),
      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    newImg.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      photo = blob;
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };

    newImg.src = url;
  }, file.type, 0.5);

  canvas.renderImage(photo);
}

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.renderImage = function(blob) {

  var canvas = this;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  }
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

input.addEventListener('change', picToBlob, false);
```

Comment: You are calling `canvas.toBlob`before you draw on it (in your `canvas.renderImage`, which is async btw) and you wonder why it outputs a transparent image? I'd say it's because you didn't drawn anything on your canvas at the time you tried to export it. Ps: in your `renderImage`, don't forget to also revoke the URL object, and you'll probably need to resize your canvas.

Answer (score 20):

I think you need to tidy up your code a bit. It's hard to know what you are trying to achieve because there are many unnecessary lines of code. The main problem is that `blob` is coming undefined here

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.renderImage = function(blob){
```

because `photo` never gets initialized here inside the `toBlob` function...which is unnecessary for what you are trying to achieve.

Here's a simplified working version of your code snippet

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var input = document.getElementById('input');


  function picToBlob() {
    canvas.renderImage(input.files[0]);
  }

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.renderImage = function(blob){
  
  var ctx = this.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  }

  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};

input.addEventListener('change', picToBlob, false);
```

```html
<input type='file' accept='image' capture='camera' id='input'>
<canvas id = 'canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: I too was looking at this approach, hoping to stick with raw data (from `getImageData`), but since `URL.createObjectURL` just [ends up creating a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) anyways I ended up skipping a step and going straight to `toDataURL` instead for my image `src`.

Comment: I don't understand why such a bad practice is upvoted, modifying prototype is a bad practice and leads to problems.

Comment: @vasilevich because the context of the question is not about best practices...if you don't like the answer then feel free to contribute by adding yours

Comment: @brichins You are mistaken: `createObjectURL` returns a _short_ URI that contains a _handle_ (aka alias, or pointer, or reference) to the already-loaded binary image data from `blob`, so it's _blazing fast_ and doesn't consume any extra RAM, whereas **using `toDataURL` is the worst way to load images and other binary data in JavaScript** because it's a blocking, synchronous function (so it freezes the browser's page thread!) and _more than doubles_ your RAM usage for each file (as `data:` URIs use Base64 encoding, which requires 125% the memory of the source binary).

Comment: Be careful when using the code in this answer: if you ever change `img.src` after `renderImage` is used then ensure that you use [`URL.revokeObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) on the old `img.src` otherwise it will have a resource-leakage bug. [MDN has a good guide on Using Object URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#using_object_urls).

Comment: @Dai you're absolutely right, I had been using `toDataURL` for HTML elsewhere on the project and didn't understand it fully. I ended up doing exactly as you stated with `createObjectURL` for subsequent projects.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap) to directly render a blob into the canvas:

```
createImageBitmap(blob).then(imageBitmap=>{ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap,0,0)})
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var input = document.getElementById('input');


function blobToCanvas() {
  createImageBitmap(input.files[0]).then(imageBitmap => {
    console.log(imageBitmap);
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0)
  })
}


input.addEventListener('change', blobToCanvas, false);
```

```html
<input type='file' accept='image' capture='camera' id='input'>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: If you have issue rendering larger images from files (via `URL.createObjectURL`) the detour via canvas helped!

Answer (score 3):

You can use it as below

```js
function renderImage(canvas, blob) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  const img = new Image()
  img.onload = (event) => {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(event.target.src) //  This is important. If you are not using the blob, you should release it if you don't want to reuse it. It's good for memory.
    ctx.drawImage(event.target, 0, 0)
  }
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
}
```

---

below is an example

```js
/**
 * @param {HTMLCanvasElement} canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API
 * @param {Blob} blob: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob
 * */
function renderImage(canvas, blob) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  switch (blob.type) {
    case "image/jpeg": // Normally, you don't need it (switch), but if you have a special case, then you can consider it.
    case "image/png":
      const img = new Image()
      img.onload = (event) => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(event.target.src) // Once it loaded the resource, then you can free it at the beginning.
        ctx.drawImage(event.target, 0, 0)
      }
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      break  
  }
}

//  below is test
(() => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
  const input = document.querySelector('input')
  input.addEventListener('change',
    (event) => {
      const file = event.target.files[0]
      const blob = new Blob(
        [file],
        {"type": file.type} // If the type is unknown, default is empty string.
      )
      renderImage(canvas, blob)
    }
  )
})()
```

```html
<div><input type='file' accept='.png,.jpg'></div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

another example to show you **What effect of the [revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL).**

```html
<div></div>
<canvas width="477" height="600"></canvas>
<script>
  async function renderImage(canvas, blob, isNeedRevoke=true) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    const img = new Image() // The upper part of the painting.
    const img2 = new Image() // The lower part of the painting.

    await new Promise(resolve => {
      img.onload = (event) => {
        if (isNeedRevoke) {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(event.target.src)
        }
        ctx.drawImage(event.target,
          0, 0, 477, 300,
          0, 0, 477, 300
        )
        resolve()
      }
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
    }).then(() => {
      img2.onload = (event) => {
        ctx.drawImage(event.target,
          0, 300, 477, 300,
          0, 300, 477, 300
        )
      }
      img2.src = img.src //  If URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src) happened, then img2.src can't find the resource, such that img2.onload will not happen.
    })
  }

  function CreateTestButton(canvas, btnText, isNeedRevoke) {
    const button = document.createElement("button")
    button.innerText = btnText
    button.onclick = async (event) => {
      canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)  // clear canvas
      fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/PNG_Test.png/477px-PNG_Test.png")
        .then(async response=>{
          const blob = await response.blob()
          renderImage(canvas, blob, isNeedRevoke)
        }).catch(err=>console.error(err))
    }
    return button
  }

  (() => {
    window.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
      const div = document.querySelector('div')
      const btn1 = CreateTestButton(canvas, "Without URL.revokeObjectURL", false)
      const btn2 = CreateTestButton(canvas, "URL.revokeObjectURL", true)
      div.append(btn1, btn2)
    }
  })()
</script>
```