# Javascript - Draw specific part of image on canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, draw

I'm trying to send images from desk to webapp, on the desk part I have a button that takes a screen-shot then compares it with the one taken before, it calculates the difference between them then generate a new Bitmap based on this difference, then it sends this new Bitmap to the webapp which draws it on a canvas, this all happens in real-time using `socket.io`.

My problem is, let's assume I use Google Chrome on my screen and took a screen-shot, then I opened `cmd.exe` & took another screenshot, assuming that cmd.exe size is 300 * 100, and starts at half of the screen, the new generated bitmap will contains the cmd.exe screen-shots but rest of the screen (the uncover parts of Google Chrome) will be black, which is perfect for my case since i want to reduce bandwidth usage, now what I want to do, is take the difference bitmap (blob) on the JavaScript side and draw the difference on the previous screen-shot, which will make it look like I transferred the whole screen-shot, If i simply parse the blobs on the canvas, It will make a black screen with the cmd.exe on the center of it, here is my current code :

```
socket.on("image up", (bin) => {
    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);  
    }
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var binaryData = [];
    binaryData.push(bin);
    img.src = urlCreator.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData));
});
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you take a look at [`context.drawImage()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) you'll see that passing extra parameters into `.drawImage` allows you to select a sub-rectangle of the to-be-drawn image and place it in a specific place on the destination canvas.  It's not exactly clear from you question want you're intentions are, but this might do the trick. :)

Comment: @BrianPeacock Sorry for not being clear about my needs, anyway, lets say I have a screenshot of my desktop on the canvas, and I have another image of cmd.exe on a variable (blobs), I need to draw the second image on top of the first one so it appears to be one screenshot of the cmd.exe on the desktop

Comment: [See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38004917/4746328).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a blob on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004917/how-to-render-a-blob-on-a-canvas-element)

Comment: No actually, rendering blobs on canvas is already done, now I have another set of blobs, and i need to render it on the same canvas but above the old image, which means let's says the first image is 1000 * 400, the second is 100*100, the second image should be on the first one at position let's say 50,50 , I think your first comment is about what I need, I will try it and get back to you, thank you very much